# How does prior probability vary with parameter?

Tags: self-study, bayesian

Suppose that there are 5 blood types in the population, named type 1 through type 5, with probabilities p1, p2,. . . , p5. A crime was committed by two individuals. A suspect, who has blood type 1, has prior probability p of being guilty. At the crime scene blood evidence is collected, which shows that one of the criminals has type 1 and the other has type 2.

Find the posterior probability that the suspect is guilty, given the evidence. Does the evidence make it more likely or less likely that the suspect is guilty, or does this depend on the values of the parameters p, p1,. . . , p5? If it depends, give a simple criterion for when the evidence makes it more likely that the suspect is guilty.

What I got so far is that P(guilty|evidence) = P(evidence|guilty)P(guilty)/(P(evidence|guilty)P(guilty)+P(evidence|not guilty)P(not guilty)).

P(guilty) = p

P(not guilty) = 1 - p

P(evidence|guilty) = 1/2 because one criminal has blood type 1

P(evidence|not guilty) = 1/5 because there are 5 blood types.

So I get P(guilty|evidence) = 0.5p/(0.5p + 0.2(1-p)) and I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: How do you get P(evidence | not guilty) = 1/5?  Look carefully at the first paragraph!

Comment: @jbowman Given that you are not guilty, would the probability be 3/5. There are blood type 3,4,and 5 who are not guilty.

Comment: Again... look carefully at the first paragraph.  Note: just because you have blood type 1 doesn't mean you are guilty!

Comment: @jbowman I was thinking of having 1 suspect with blood type 1 out of 5 blood types. If it is given that the person is not guilty, then there are three blood types that are not guilty so it should be 3/5?

Comment: The blood types are not guilty!  I can have blood type 1 and still be innocent!   You are overlooking a key piece of information as well, the probabilities of the blood types in the population given in the first sentence.

Comment: @jbowman The probability of getting blood type 1 and 2 in evidence given you are not guilty is p1+p2. Is that right?

Comment: No, and to see why not, imagine that you have 5 suspects with blood types 1-5.  If you sum the probabilities p1 + p2 + ... + p5 you get 1, but the actual probability that you get exactly one of each blood type in five individuals obviously cannot be 100%.